# HTML/CSS List issue

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML/CSS coding. I am in the middle of a project for my summer class and I am stumped. Part of my project is to make a HTML list of three tags with the angle brackets included. I know how to add a tag using the angle brackets (< >) but I don't know how to add the tag into the list without the tag actually working. I need to find a way to add the tag into the list with brackets and not have the tag work so it can show up like this:
My favorite tags are:

1.em

2.p

3.q

but with the brackets.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to write the HTML-encoded versions of `<` and `>`, which are `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem what you need is to use HTML ENTITIES.

Here is a link with Full Explanation: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

For "<" you have to use `&lt;`
For ">" you have to use `&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the tag characters. `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>`.

HTML code:

```
<ol>
  <li>&lt;em&gt;</li>
  <li>&lt;p&gt;</li>
  <li>&lt;q&gt;</li>
</ol>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ED6T9/)